# Phonegap Online event fire only after state change

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have to check for network connection on app start, but PhoneGap online/offline event fires after any state change to it. If the app starts in online mode, the online events doesn't fired, until it gets offline, then comes online.

This is the code,

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {        
    document.addEventListener("offline", this.onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", this.onOnline, false);
},
```

That's wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online/offline events are made to fire on state change only. 
If you need to check the connectivity at a certain point, you can use [navigator.network.connection.type](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html#connection.type).

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {        
    document.addEventListener("offline", this.onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", this.onOnline, false);
    if((navigator.network.connection.type).toUpperCase() == "NONE" && 
       (navigator.network.connection.type).toUpperCase() == "UNKNOWN") {
        this.onOffline();
    }
    else {
        this.onOnline();
    }   
},
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, i thought this had gone depricated